# AngularJS not loading directive correctly when using services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, highcharts

I am new to JavaScript and working on something where I retrieve data from MongoDB and writing code on AngularJS to draw a pie chart using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com). Code works fine when I am using just Angular controller without service but doesn't work when use service in between even though I hard code data in service. I am giving here working code and non-working code as well. I need to make this working using services as I need to read the actual data from MongoDB.

Below is my HTML file and JavaScript code for controller, service, etc. I have even hardcoded response that I am getting from service into controller to make sure it has data the way it is expected but still it is not drawing chart as expected.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/twittersentimentcontroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/twittersentimentservice.js"></script>
<script src="js/core.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="hc-pie" items="limitedIdeas"></div>
    <div items="limitedIdeas">{{limitedIdeas}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller, directive, services code is as below.

```
angular.module('myController', [])

    // inject the Todo service factory into our controller
    .controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http','some', function($scope, $http, some) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        console.log("inside controller...............");    

        some.get("android")
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.sentiments = [["Positive", 26], ["Negative", 5], ["Nutral", 69]];
                $scope.ideas = [["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]];
                $scope.limitedIdeas = [["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]];
                $scope.loading = false;
            });    
    }]);

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('hcPie', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log(2);

    },
    template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">not working....Please work....</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(3);
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
          percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#000000',
              connectorColor: '#000000',
              formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Browser share',
          data: scope.items
        }]
      });
      scope.$watch("items", function (newValue) {
        chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
      }, true);

    }
  }
});
```

Services:

```
angular.module('someService', [])

    // super simple service
    // each function returns a promise object 
    .factory('some', ['$http',function($http) {
        return {
            get : function(instrument) {
                return $http.get('/api/sent/'+instrument);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Below is the code how we connect controller, service together.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myController', 'someService']);
```

Web page does display `[["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]]` value when I try to display them so hard coded value on controller is there on scope but for some reason my directive is not loading correctly.

If I do below code directly without service or something, it works fine and it does draw entire pie-chart as expected but why it doesn't work when I use the same thing via services. As I mentioned, my service does work correctly and I see that it gets me exact that data I am expecting in the expected format as well (I have hard coded same thing here).

**Please check below code which works fine and draws the pie chart alright but not above code using service doesn't work. Can you help what is wrong with above code?**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="hc-pie" items="limitedIdeas"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function MyCtrl($scope, limitToFilter) {
  $scope.ideas = [
    ['ideas1', 1],
    ['ideas2', 8],
    ['ideas3', 5]
  ];

  $scope.limitedIdeas = limitToFilter($scope.ideas, 3);
}

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('hcPie', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log(2);

    },
    template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">not working</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(3);
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
          percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#000000',
              connectorColor: '#000000',
              formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Browser share',
          data: scope.items
        }]
      });
      scope.$watch("items", function (newValue) {
        chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
      }, true);

    }
  }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be careful, `angular.module('myApp', [])` is a setter, and you use it two times, you should use it to instantiate your app, but use `angular.module('myApp')` after for a getter

Could you also change '.success' by '.then' please. .then use the promise system

you wrote 'instr' instead of 'instrument', can you change it ?

```
 .factory('some', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {
        get : function(instrument) {
            return $http.get('/api/sent/'+instrument);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I changed some little things in your plunker and it works for me, if you dont have the data you want, you should watch in your back-end side http://plnkr.co/edit/ZShnouXLEVNxD1NHdev2?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for answering Thomas. I have changed that but issue is still same. Chart is not loaded even after I have added hard coded value in the service but It works fine on without service code.

Comment: can you console log 'scope.items' in your directive ?

Comment: Where you want me to do console log on the directive? I have done exactly after declaration of directive but its not printing anything. I mean not even simple "inside directive" string so it is not being called at all. I am sorry I am making some silly mistakes but very new to node JS and mainly from java background so syntex are confusing for me. Here is where I am doing console log. angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('hcPie', function () {
   console.log("inside directive: "+$scope.items);

Comment: I have replaced .success with .then as well. Still same thing.

Comment: controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log($scope.items);

    },

Comment: It's not printing anything there also. This is what I have not now but nothing on console logs.     controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
   console.log("inside directive: "+$scope.items);
      console.log(2);
    }

Comment: I have console log statement under actual controller as well but it is not printing that as well but I know that controller is being called as web page is showing "[["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]]" value when I load the page so controller is being called but nothing on console logs. nothing is printing when i do console.log. this is the biggest reason as I am not able to debug much here.  .controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http','twitterSentiments', function($scope, $http, twitterSentiments) {
  $scope.loading = true;
  console.log("inside controller...............");

Comment: try to change angular.module('myController', []) by angular.module('myApp', [])

Comment: Than it is not working at all. Web page doesn't show any value and display just "{{limitedIdeas}}". I think it may be because I already have angular.module('myApp', ['twitterSentimentController', 'twitterSentimentService']); line in the separate JS file already. As I mentioned above, I know that controller is being called as web page is showing "[["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]]" value when I try to print "limitedIdeas" item under div on HTML code so controller is being called but nothing on console logs. nothing is printing when i do console.log on controller as well.

Comment: Here is the working code plunker for which chart loads fine. This is without service version. I am creating the other service non-working plunker now. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAzegtKKemuC7bjmDuws?p=preview

Comment: Here is the non-working plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/bW0JpSUI1kCB7Un4992m). For some reason this is not displaying hard coded version "[["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]]". May be because my service calls some URL which talks to mongo but in this case, it is not able to get that data so it is failing?  Not sure. On my local, i do see it is displaying "[["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]]" value on webpage.

Comment: I am not sure there is any way to fake the response from Service so I have kept it as it is. As I mentioned on above comment, my local web page display: [["Positive",2],["Negative",5],["Nutral",69]] value where as plunker web page display: {{limitedIdeas}} value.

Comment: I changed  'instr' instead of 'instrument' as well and it is still same thing.

Comment: You are a super start man. Thank you so much. It works fine. Just for my information, what was I doing wrong? Wanted to know what I should do it to fix this next time?

Comment: I dont remember so much, but it was just little mistake, you should check  your console more i thin, good luck